# How do i create multiple instances of widgets in Qt dynamically

Tags: c++, qt, model-view-controller, qt-creator, qt6

iam trying to add multiple widgets dynamically but by calling a function that creates a widget, the issue is i dont know how to make multiple instances of widgets and refer to a specific one.

i bacically wana have a button that when i press creates a tab (in tabwidget) and a QTableView inside of each tab

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_7_clicked()
{   
    table = new QTableView;
    ui->tabWidget->insertTab(ui->tabWidget->count(), table, QIcon(QString("")), "New Playlist");

    //table->setColumnCount(4);



    table->horizontalHeader()->setVisible(true);
    table->verticalHeader()->setVisible(false);
    table->setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView::SelectRows);
    table->setShowGrid(false);
}
```

so as you can see i have a `on_pushButton_7_clicked()` fucntion, that i wana call multiple times in my program, and (as i wanted) creates inserts a Tab and a TableView in that tab, so far so good, thats what i wanted, but when i call the function 2nd time, the `table` variable now gets reassigned to latest created QTableView, i wana be able to create multiple of those and access a specific one, any way to do this?

excpecting to access each instance of `table` if there is a different way to do this, iam happy to try

Answer (score 0):

You need to store a collection of tables. Say it's a `QList`

```
// QTableView* table;
QList<QTableView*> tables;
```

Then change your function to:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_7_clicked()
{   
    QTableView *table = new QTableView;
    //ui->tabWidget->insertTab(ui->tabWidget->count(), table, QIcon(QString("")), "New Playlist");
    // it's probably better to give unique names to the tabs:
    QString name = QString("New Playlist %1").arg(ui->tabWidget->count());
    ui->tabWidget->insertTab(ui->tabWidget->count(), table, QIcon(QString("")), name);
    
    // it's even better to set the name to the table:
    table->setObjectName(name);

    //table->setColumnCount(4);

    table->horizontalHeader()->setVisible(true);
    table->verticalHeader()->setVisible(false);
    table->setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView::SelectRows);
    table->setShowGrid(false);

    tables->append(table);
}
```

In fact, you don't really need to store a collection of `tables`. They are already stored in `ui->tabWidget` and you can access them via [widget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtabwidget.html#widget) function.